# How to fix black screen of a mkv file with mplayer?

Tags: ubuntu, mplayer

Using mplayer (1.1-4.8) on an ubuntu 14.04 system just plays the sound, but leaves the video screen black.

With `vlc` and `xine` it also does not work (Sound yes, but no video).

Are there some magic options to make it work with mplayer, or some options to re-encode the whole video file?

Comment: As you must already realize, there are tons of different codecs that could be involved in a video file and identifying the missing codec is the first step to resolve the problem.

Comment: And how to do that?